# c# Elastic Search Nest if output document scores are the same order by id

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'am using the below code to get a list of results based on a given query. What i would like to do is if the document scores are equal to each other is to then order the results by id with the lowest number coming first.

Note this should only affect the documents that have equal scores to each other and not all given results and I will limit results to the best 10.

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Place>(s => s
             .From(0)
             .Size(10)
             .TrackScores(true)
             .Query(q => q

                    .QueryString(fqqs1 => fqqs1
                        .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                            .Add("name", 5.0)
                        )
                        .Query("birmingham, south east hospital")
                    )

             )
             .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
       );
```

Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok then order by id after you order by score. Like this:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Place>(s => s
         .From(0)
         .Size(10)
         .TrackScores(true)
         .Query(q => q

                .QueryString(fqqs1 => fqqs1
                    .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                        .Add("name", 5.0)
                    )
                    .Query("birmingham, south east hospital")
                )

         )
         .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
         .Sort(sort => sort.OnField(f=>f.Id).Ascending())
   );
```